# Oracle db password with $ not working in rman

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, rman, oracle-dump

my oracle database user name is SYSTEM and password is smith123$

I tried to execute a backup shell script
**su - root -c "rman target SYSTEM/smith123$@ORCL cmdfile /home/oracle/dbDump/rman.ls
"**

I got the folllowing error while running the above script

**Recovery Manager: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 25 13:19:00 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-04005: error from target database:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**

Any help to resolve it ?

Comment: Very probably the shell is trying to substitute $@, so escape the $ in your command (\$). Probably a  better solution would be to put the connect in the cmdfile

Comment: I tried the both ways ,
**su - root -c "rman target SYSTEM/smith123\$@ORCL cmdfile /home/oracle/dbDump/rman.ls "**
and 
cmdfile change 
**connect target SYSTEM/smith123\$@ORCL
run {**

I got the below errors in both of the tried ways
**RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

**

Comment: I changed the cmdfile 
 **connect target "SYSTEM/smith123$" 
 run {**
Its working